# How to make a custom error page using .htaccess file

Tags: php, html, css, .htaccess

I am trying to raise a custom error page for each error

Here is my directory

```
.htaccess
error_pages:
           error_400.html
           error_401.html
           error_404.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've tagged your question `php`, but used `.html` in your example? If you are using PHP then you don't need separate error documents for each HTTP status. You can use the same PHP error document and check the `REDIRECT_STATUS` (ie. `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_STATUS']` superglobal) in order to determine the status of the error that triggered the error document.

So, your `.htaccess` file would consist of:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /error_pages/error_handler.php
ErrorDocument 401 /error_pages/error_handler.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error_pages/error_handler.php
```

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errordocument

Comment: Thank you MrWhite you have always been in my back, Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You are close. First, if you have not done so already, you'll need to initialize your .htaccess document.

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Next, you'll need to define the error and tell .htaccess which file to use for that error:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /error_pages/error_400.html
ErrorDocument 401 /error_pages/error_401.html
ErrorDocument 404 /error_pages/error_404.html
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: `RewriteEngine On` - this enables the _rewrite engine_ (as you might guess), ie. mod_rewrite. This has nothing to do with `ErrorDocument` (which is a _core_ directive). Nothing needs to be done to "initialize your `.htaccess`" - simply creating the file is enough.